# Want to be able to sign up subscribers as authors

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, themes, widgets, user-roles

I want to be able to select a subscriber an author of a post in the admin so it displays their name as having written the post, but I do not want to give them any additional privileges (if they login the only thing they can access is their profile).

I saw a solution up here, but when I used that hack, it left other users off of the author drop-down (e.g., contributor, etc.). In addition, I'm going to end up having 100s of contributors I want to include as subscribers/authors, but I imagine that would destroy the dropdown or make it very difficult. Any suggestions would be so welcome and thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Posts 2 Posts plugin...it may be able to handle easily associating certain posts with certain users regardless of user-role capablities.  It is especially useful if you have some sort of multiple author setup.

[wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/)

Comment: Thank you so much, Douglas. I will check it out. I truly appreciate it!! :)